# How to set width of div by class name

Tags: html, css, sass, less

I don't need it, just have a interest, there is way set width or other only by class without style attribute.
For example:

```
<div class="block-500"></div>


div.block-#{$value} {
  width: $value;
}
```

And in class can be any value.
Thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

Comment: With pure CSS it is not possible. You don't know what value you can use for the class name, like `block-1234`. You can create a SASS/LESS loop that and add some upper limit, like 9999, to create every class with that number as a prefix - `block-9999` will be the largest. But that will create a large CSS file so it's not a good solution. My 5 cents, if You have this issue use JS to look for every `block-` element and create with JS a CSS class selector with all the prefixes used.

Comment: @Vucko, sadly(. Maybe then in this case the better solution will be using style attribute or js. Thanks)

Comment: I meant suffix* , sorry for the inconvenience. With inline styles is possible, as described in the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Try this you can achieve in this way.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .container {
            background: red;
            width: var(--width);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" style="--width: 300px;">Content</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, it's working. But there is way only using class without style attribute?

Comment: for now, I know to do like this...  I will explore this and let you if there is the possibility to do it with only using class

Comment: ow, thanks. It will be fine) I think it is possible, but don't know how